# Zigbee protocol for local indoor sensor like a Beacon (Low Battery) is Possible or exist?

Tags: protocols, zigbee

I would like to start some studies on a new area, look for new solutions, because I already work in an automation company, but first I would like to know if it counts, if it has pros or cons or your opinion, it may seem like ahahh science fiction subject, but I would like to know if:

Is it possible or is there any solution in which I use the communication network zigbee as low energy, only with battery, like the Beacons?

And why this may not be possible?

Are there any chances of me developing a passive / active module as an xbee that uses little resources, just the necessary and battery operated?
I say, should I develop or study a circuit myself, or do have any premises that prevent?

Comment: This question is far too broad. You've given no indication of expected range or battery life you are looking for. Also what problem are you trying to solve with this idea? What does creating a Zigbee beacon get you over say a BLE beacon? Plus there are already many battery powered Zigbee devices (e.g. Ikea Tradfri remotes)

Comment: It would be for presence sensors, small range, only for indoor environments, like 5 meters, battery could last about 2 years, with much research I found that xbee has a "sleeping" profile but still not "passive / active" like beacons
Sorry for the broad question, but as I said, I'm still studying hard and the internet doesn't have as much information about, did not know about the remotes Ikea Tradfri, thank you very much, I will search more now with this information!

Comment: As hardillb says, this question's a little broad — it's best to focus on just one question with a specific goal rather than multiple. Please do [edit] to update and clarify and we can get your question reopened—be sure to read the [tour] and [ask] for some tips.

Comment: The last edit hasn't added any clarity to this question.

Comment: forgive my english but i'm trying my best to make it clear to the community

Comment: There are plenty of battery-powered Zigbee sensors, including motion sensors and many more (smoke sensors, water leak sensors, contact sensors for doors/windows...) from many brands, including Philips Hue, Ikea Tradfri, Osram, Smartthings, Xiaomi, and many more. You'll find a list of many of them [here](https://github.com/dresden-elektronik/deconz-rest-plugin/wiki/Supported-Devices#supported-sensors)